# Nuxt generate ERROR Cannot read property '__esModule' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

When I run `nuxt generate` on my project it generates this error several times:

```
 ERROR  Cannot read property '__esModule' of undefined                    11:09:43

  at ensureCtor (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:2262:10)
  at node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:2317:26
  at node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:324:10
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I would report it as a bug but I failed to reproduce it outside of my closed-source project. I'm also not sure if it's an issue with Vue or Nuxt, might even be both.

The error seems to be related to using async components which I do use. The line causing the error is in an async component resolver: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/helpers/resolve-async-component.js#L18

My project has other configurations too that don't use async components and are not having this issue.

What I would like to know is how it might be possible to avoid these errors and still use async components.

Comment: which version of Nuxt.js ? and Node.js ?

Comment: Vue 2.5.17, Nuxt 2.3.1, Node 10.14.0